# Vue 3 shows previous route in onMounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using Vue with a dynamic navigation based on my backend. An endpoint decides what page to display based on the current route.

I've made a simplified version below with the relevant parts. Everything works fine, except for when I use a `<router-link>` or `router.push` to one of my routes. In the `onMounted` callback of my target page, the route seems to be the previous route (see AboutView.vue below).

I've tried `await router.isReady()`, but as far as I can tell it's not relevant here, it's only used for an initial page view.

Sample repo built with node 16.13.2: https://github.com/tietoevry-johan/vue-routing

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-view/>
</template>
```

**router.ts**

```
export const currentPage = ref('HomeView')

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      name: "PageSelector",
      path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
      component: PageSelector
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach(async (to, _, next) => {
  currentPage.value = await getComponentByPath(to.path)
  next()
})

async function getComponentByPath(path: string) {
  return path === '/' ? 'HomeView' : 'AboutView'
}
```

**PageSelector.vue**

```
<template>
  <component :is="currentPage" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue"
import AboutView from "@/views/AboutView.vue"
import HomeView from "@/views/HomeView.vue"
import { currentPage } from "@/router"

export default defineComponent({
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-components
  components: { HomeView, AboutView },
  setup() {
    return {
      currentPage
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

**AboutView.vue**

```
<template>
  about
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import router from "@/router";
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(router.currentRoute.value?.fullPath) // prints / instead of /about
      // when clicking a router link or router push to this page
    })
  }
})

</script>
```

Comment: This router setup looks quite flaky. There's obviously race condition that depends on router internals. It shouldn't be expected that a route is changed instantly after beforeEach The thing that can be done here is to use afterEach at least. Or to watch currentRoute changes in root or PageSelector comp

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, I was just thinking about watching currentRoute in the PageSelector. I guess that's pretty much how the router-view works, e.g. resolve component by matching route and render it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from navigating to the current route, which updates current route parameters, but doesn't trigger a reload of the component in `<router-view>`, while a side-effect changes how the component behaves. The side effect is triggered in the router's `beforeEach()`, and apparently the update in the component is handled before the current route parameters are updated.

---

The easiest fix is the one @EstusFlask recommended in the comments, just use `afterEach()` instead of `beforeEach()`:

```
router.afterEach(async (to) => {
  currentPage.value = await getComponentByPath(to.path)
})
```

This will update the variable after current route has been updated, giving you the desired order of events.

[playground using afterEach()](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/funny-robinson-cpw4gd?file=%2Fsrc%2Frouter%2Findex.js%3A19%2C57)

---

A more robust approach is to not mix router functionality and component functionality. For this, you add a prop to your PageSelector, which determines the rendered page:

```html
<template>
  <component :is="currentPage ?? 'HomeView'" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import AboutView from "./AboutView.vue";
import HomeView from "./HomeView.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: { HomeView, AboutView },
  props: ["currentPage"],
});
</script>
```

Now you can remove the `beforeEach`/`afterEach` hook, and instead pass in the prop through the route:

```
export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      name: "PageSelector",
      path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
      component: PageSelector,
      props: (route) => ({
        currentPage: getComponentByPath(route.path),
      }),
    },
  ],
});
```

Now you can use regular props instead of the hidden state variable.

[playground using router props](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bold-cherry-fj2dpn?file=%2Fsrc%2Frouter%2Findex.js%3A11%2C28)

Might be worth thinking about if matching string to component should happen in PageSelector instead of a function in router (`getComponentByPath()`), as you probably want to avoid running PageSelector without a matched component. In your question, `getComponentByPath()` is declared async, despite not doing anything asynchronously - if this is not a mistake, moving it into the component will allow you to handle the async event with more control.

[playground with component matching in PageSelector](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/inspiring-herschel-vtjvm4?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FPageSelector.vue%3A1%2C1)

---

Expanding on the above approach, you could also make PageSelector a transient page, that just resolves the actual route for the given props and then redirects to the actual page, which are also defined routes:

```
export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      name: "PageSelector",
      path: "/loading/:pageId",
      component: PageSelector,
      props: true
    },
    {
      name: "HomeView",
      path: "/home",
      component: HomeView
    },
    ...
  ],
});
```

The PageSelector component shows a loading screen while the actual route is resolved and then redirects to it. All necessary data can be passed as route params. The advantage here is that PageSelector can focus on complex things (like error handling), but routes themselves work independently and loading can be skipped if not necessary.

[playground where PageSelector uses redirect](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/currying-haze-c3m72m?file=%2Fsrc%2Frouter%2Findex.js%3A19%2C23)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In short, the actual PageSelector is close to what I have in my example. The reason for using this setup is because the routes are fetched from an API, I can't  create them beforehand in a router config. The prop approach is interesting, but my actual `getComponentByPath` is async, so I guess that's out of the question. Right now I'm leaning towards watching `router.currentRoute` inside the PageSelector and doing `getComponentByPath` in its callback. What do you think about that approach?

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Interesting. I would still try to keep router logic and PageSelector logic separate, you don't gain anything from mixing them up, except fuzzy logic and interfering hooks.  Have you looked at the "component with page selector" example? It resolves the component asynchronously in the PageSelector. Wouldn't that work for you too?

Comment: I have replace the last approach with a version where PageSelector just loads the route and then redirects. Not sure if this works with your use case. My assumption is that the components are all available and can be turned into routes, but the API is necessary to figure out which component is needed for a given identifier (i.e. does this user get the adimin page or the regular user page). Does that make sense? Let me know if that approach works for you.

Comment: Ah yes, your component with page selector is an interesting take on it. As a reference, check out the official router here https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/src/RouterView.ts#L138C19-L138C19.  It injects the current route (a.k.a. router.currentRoute), find the matching route in the config along with its component and uses a render function to render it instead of our `<component :is...>. Not sure if there's any upside of a render function in this case? I'll put the points here tomorrow when the timer runs out, thanks for a good talk so far

Comment: Oh, wow, thank you! Using a render function should not make a difference. Some things are easier expressed in a render function, but the template compiler gives you better optimized code, as it uses more low-level functions than you typically would in a manual render function. There is a detailed explanation in the [documentation on the rendering mechanism](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism.html#templates-vs-render-functions). To see the difference, have a look at generated render functions by popping a `console.log(this._.render.toString());` somewhere in a component

Comment: I see. Thanks for a good talk :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @Moritz Ringler and @Estus Flask, I just want to point that in my opinion the root cause of this behavior is that vue-router reuses the components of dynamic routes. You can test that onMounted is called only once in `pageSelector`. Thus, the child dynamic component after the mount of `pageSelector` behaves totally independent of route navigation, being dependent only on update of `currentPage` value. In this case, since all routes have the same component, the navigation itself from one route to another has no effect on any of the components, the router being used only to update a variable which is the trigger for component change.

To sum up, in my opinion, whith the code provided in the original post, the router is almost unneeded, the same functionality being possible with a function that [calls the endpoint and] updates the value of `currentPage`.

PS: In case the router is kept, in line with the mentioned above, another solution would be to prevent `vue-router` from reusing the route component by binding the `route.fullPath` to the key of the route component/dynamic component.

Comment: I see what you mean, but at the end of the day this is pretty much what the vue router does too. The lifecycles of the dynamic components works just as regular "views". Just as you said, it can be controlled with :key depending on how you want things to be reused. I was thinking about ditching the router too, but it has its built in way of dealing with pushState, query/params and scrollBehaviour which is pretty nice to make use of.